# How to calculate the average ratings for the post when the user submits 3 field ratings?

Tags: nodes, entities, rating

I need to implement ratings in my site. I have user five star rating and voting API module, I created a content_type with "beach", and created some field in the manage field settings, name, id, etc. And also I configured the five star module with tags like location ratings, beachratings, facilites ratings and overall (average ratings) ratings. I display all the rating stars in the page by using the code.

```
$bid=explode("/",$_GET['q']);
$node = node_load($bid['1']);// we get the node id here//
$fivestar = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_overall_ratings');
echo render($fivestar);
$beachrating=field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_beaches_ratings');
echo render($beachrating);
$locationrating=field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_location_ratings');
echo render($locationrating);
$easyrating=field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_easy_to_get');
echo render($easyrating);
```

When I submit the ratings, they are stored in the database but the average is not updating.
But I need to calculate the overall ratings when the user votes for the three section. Can anyone help me how can we implement this in my site?

Answer (score 0):

Use `fivestar_get_votes` to get individual widgets **average** and get **average** of them to have **average** rating of the entire node.

Comment: hi nikhil , can send me some examples how can i use in the site and field , are alter the code code let me use that and check